# JSON how to call an object in a different list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json

I currently have an JSON API that looks like this:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 277,
      "title": "test title",
      "content": "test content",
      "attachments": [
        {
          "url": "http:\/\/www.example.com\/bar-icon-help@2x.png"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the "url" which is under "attachments". Please take a look at what im doing wrong:

```
-(void)dataRequestCompletedWithJsonObject.(id)jsonObject
{
    NSDictionary *recipeDictionary = (NSDictionary*)jsonObject;

    NSArray* recipeArray = (NSArray*)[recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];

    self.recipes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary* dic in recipeArray) {

        Recipe *recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];

        recipe.name = [dic objectForKey:@"title"];
        recipe.thumbNail = [[dic objectForKey:@"attachements"]objectForKey:@"url"];
        recipe.twitterShareCount = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];

        [recipes addObject:recipe];
    }
```

Mainly trying to figure out what i should use instead of this line:

```
recipe.thumbNail = [[dic objectForKey:@"attachements"]objectForKey:@"url"];
```

Thanks to anyone who helps!

Comment: [dic objectForKey:@"attachements"] is an array of one dictionary and not a dictionary.

Comment: are you missing a "]" in your JSON example near the end?

Comment: It confuses the issue when you don't provide valid JSON as any one answering has to make guesses at the actual structure...

Comment: Sorry, I'm following a beginners tutorial on using json. I'm merely changing the tutorial to use my own API

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of dicts in attachments object.

```
[[[dic objectForKey:@"attachements"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"url"]
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote example for object at index 0. Just to show you that there is an array. You need to check if list count is greater then 0 and enumerate through the list to process all urls. That's how you should handle all cases correctly.